# Laravel composer require laravel/ui^2.4 also not working. 1.0 --dev not working too

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8.0 version.

Problem 1
- facade/ignition is locked to version 2.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- facade/ignition 2.4.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- facade/ignition-contracts 1.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
- nunomaduro/collision v4.3.0 requires facade/ignition-contracts ^1.0 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition-contracts[1.0.1].
- nunomaduro/collision is locked to version v4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5OQX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull in laravel/ui v 3.x version 2.x is not compatible with Laravel 8.x

https://github.com/laravel/ui

If you have a "laravel/ui": "^2.4" in your composer.json, remove it and run

```sh
composer update
```

And then pull in the package

```sh
composer require laravel/ui
```

Or you can just update the entry in composer.json to

```json
"require": {
    "laravel/ui": "^3.0"
}
```

And then run

```sh
composer update
```